# Help me integrate this function...

Tags: integration, derivatives

How can I integrate this function: $$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ Can I somehow square it then root it later?

Comment: Try $x=\sin{y}$

Comment: Sry, I don't get the point...

Comment: It's called a substitution. If you haven't learned this yet, that integral is probably too hard.

Comment: Yeah, I know what substitution is, but, I can't visualize what it will solve in this case... Can you please explain it further in an answer? I'd appreciate it a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\sin\theta.$

Since $dx/d\theta=\cos\theta\iff dx=\cos\theta\cdot d\theta,$
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}&=\int\frac{\cos\theta\cdot d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}\\&=\int\frac{\cos\theta}{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}}d\theta\\&=\int d\theta\\&=\theta+C\\&=\arcsin x+C.\end{align}$$

Comment: Why is 1=cos $\theta$

Comment: Well, what part are you talking about? I added a bit. Does this help?

Comment: The substitution part, I understand the denominator, but the numerator is confusing me...

Comment: Remember that $$\cos^{2}\theta + sin^{2} \theta = 1 $$

Comment: Why is 1 then transformed to $cos\theta$

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I used $dx/d\theta=\cos\theta$. see the difference between the two.

Comment: Can you explain that step in another comment please :D

Comment: Phrasing differently what Autolatry said, $dx=d(\sin\theta)=\cos\theta d\theta$. It is not the 1 which is transformed but the differential - look at the formula for the change of variable (substitution) in an integral.

Comment: I get it now :D Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @A6Tech : OK. I added a bit.